# Resolving Windows phone 8.1 Compilation Error: GetENumerator

Tags: c#, casting, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the onNavigate method in windows phone 8.1 and trying to pass a list of navigation objects I have created. When I try and retrieve the list from e.parameters (which seems to work) I cannot iterate through the list and cast them back to the original object types. It works if I send a single object but not a list.

For Example.

From a button_click event on the mainpage I am calling the code below to navigate to page2 and pass a list of objects.

**I have a class defined as below.**

```
class NavigationContext 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**For testing I create 3 objects and add it to a list as follows**

```
  NavigationContext navobj = new NavigationContext(){ID = 77,Name = "DN",  Description = "TD1"};

  NavigationContext navobj2 = new NavigationContext(){ID = 22,Name = "JN",Description = "JD1"};

  NavigationContext navobj3 = new NavigationContext(){ID = 22,Name = "CN",Description = "CN1"};
```

**I then create the list as below**

```
    List<NavigationContext> navlist = new List<NavigationContext>(){navobj,navobj2,navobj3};
```

**I then Make the call below**

```
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), navlist);
```

**If I pass one object the code works and compiles and the new page is navigated too sucessfully*
**If I pass a list as above I get the following error on the foreach iterator in the OnNavigatedTo method**

**Example code below*

```
 string myfiller = "";

foreach (NavigationContext navobj in e.Parameter)
{
myfiller += navobj.ID.ToString() + "  " + navobj.Name + "  " + navobj.Description+ "\n";
}
```

I get the following error:
*foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for GetENumerator.*

I have tried to find ways to cast the list back to NavigationContext objects but I think I am doing something stupid because I cann0t get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your problem is right in the error message: `e.Parameter` is an `object` but you want to iterate over it, so cast it to something that iterates.

Comment: doing a google search on the exact error message yields the following [cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for GetENumerator](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20cannot%20operate%20on%20variables%20of%20type%20%27object%27%20because%20%27object%27%20does%20not%20contain%20a%20public%20definition%20for%20GetENumerator) show more effort and do a search on the error msg it's telling you exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<NavigationContext> navigationObjects = e.Parameter as List<NavigationContext>;
if(null != navigationObjects)
{
    foreach (NavigationContext navobj in navigationObjects)
    {
        myfiller += navobj.ID.ToString() + "  " + navobj.Name + "  " + navobj.Description+ "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that if the e.Parameter object cannot be interpreted as the correct type (a `List<NavigationContext>`) then using the `as` operator will result in a `null` value that can be tested to prevent further problems when you try to use the elements of the list as `NavigationContext` objects.

Comment: `NULL` won't compile. Make it `null`. In my opinion it is better to express if your object equals nothing then if nothing equals your object, because it sounds more logical. `if(navigationObjects != null)`

Comment: @Silvermind Editted answer, thanks for pointing that out.  The order doesn't make much difference in C#, but putting an immutable on the left helps to reduce the possibility of doing assignment within the conditional statement by accident.  (I don't know if you can do that in C#, but it happens all too often in C.)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how to cast the list back to the objects. Now I know.

Comment: @MikeofSST I don't know about C, but if you make that mistake in C#, it will result in a compiler error, since it won't evaluate to a Boolean.